# Double tapping j in insert mode exits insert mode

Tags: vim

I've managed to break my vim such that if I double tap `j` in insert mode then it exits insert mode without typing either of the `j`s. I've done a full restart and no joy follows.

What have I managed to do?

Comment: Sounds more like a riddle :). Try to run vim with no configuration: `vim -u NONE`. Once you confirm it's your configuration that's causing the issue, just try to comment out (prepend with `"`) stuff in your `.vimrc` until it works.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out thanks to Kent.

```
:iunmap jj
:iunmap kk
```

No idea how they magically got mapped to  all of a sudden (vimrc says nothing).

It's entirely possible that I've just not noticed this behaviour before... I've been using it for a good 4-5 years though :(

Comment: That's weird :). `:version` will show you all configuration files vim is using (system-wide vimrc, default vimrc, etc.), that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your .vimrc looks like, it is hard to tell exactly what you've done. If you want to do a full reset of vim, you'll have to delete the ~/.vimrc file and have vim regenerate it's default settings, which should fix your problem, but also break any other permanent modifications you've made to vim's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

add this to the bottom of your vimrc:

```
:imap jj <Esc>
```

Comment: Looks like that is what it was set to. Put me on the right track for fixing this though, thank you!